# One object handling multiple extended objects with same code

Tags: java

I would like to have one object handle multiple extended objects. The end result should be is I pass a Bike or MotorBike it will display the information. In my example below I want a class (Display) to accept Bike or MotorBike (which extends Bike) and display the information appropriately. The failure point is in Display, the last line printing the information unique to MotorBike. I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I just don't get what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks for your help.

Problem.java

```
public class Problem {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Display(new Bike());
        new Display(new MotorBike());
    }
}
```

Bike.java

```
class Bike {
    private boolean frontTireOk;
    private boolean backTireOk;
    private int gears;

    public Bike() {}

    public boolean isFrontTireOk() {
        return frontTireOk;
    }

    public void setFrontTireOk(boolean frontTireOk) {
        this.frontTireOk = frontTireOk;
    }

    public boolean isBackTireOk() {
        return backTireOk;
    }

    public void setBackTireOk(boolean backTireOk) {
        this.backTireOk = backTireOk;
    }

    public int getGears() {
        return gears;
    }

    public void setGears(int gears) {
        this.gears = gears;
    }
}
```

MotorBike,java

```
class MotorBike extends Bike {

    private int engineCC;

    public MotorBike() {}

    public int getEngineCC() {
        return engineCC;
    }

    public void setEngineCC(int engineCC) {
        this.engineCC = engineCC;
    }
}
```

Display.java

```
class Display {

    Bike bike;

    public Display(Bike bike) {
        this.bike = (Bike) bike;
        showBike();
    }

    Display(MotorBike motorBike) {
        this.bike = (MotorBike) motorBike;
        showBike();
    }

    private void showBike() {

        System.out.println("Front tire is OK ?" + bike.isFrontTireOk());
        System.out.println("Back tire is OK? " + bike.isBackTireOk());
        System.out.println("Gears? " + bike.getGears());

        if(bike instanceof MotorBike){
            System.out.println("Engine CC? " + bike.getEngineCC()); <--FAIL
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the line

```
System.out.println("Engine CC? " + bike.getEngineCC());
```

You're accessing the method 'getEngineCC' from member 'bike', but 'bike' is of type Bike, not MotorBike, so the method 'getEngineCC' can't be fetched if you just use 'bike' on its own. Try typecasting:

```
System.out.println("Engine CC? " + ((MotorBike)bike).getEngineCC());
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew it was something simple. Well, simple if you know. :)